# What is line-height:1?

Tags: css

It is a question about the appointment of line-height.

I began study of css. 
line-height: Examples appointing 20px or a unit are often found.
It is sometimes line-height: There are 1 and a thing without a unit, but what kind of meaning does this become?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values

Answer (score 38):

> Possible Values

**number** :

Sets a number that will be multiplied with the current font-size to set the distance 
between the lines

**length**  :

Sets a fixed distance between the lines

**%** :

Sets a distance between the lines in % of the current font size

take from http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: If setting the line-height **without a unit**, the result is the **line-height value multiplied by the element’s font-size**. The line-height property can accept unitless values. This is a good article detailing the [line-height property](https://kolosek.com/css-line-height/).

Answer (score 12):

Also note:
"1" does not equal "normal" - 1 is exactly the same height as the font-size, so the lines in a multi-line element such as a paragraph will be snug up against each other, while normal adds the expected spacing between the lines.

Using the font shorthand:

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;
```

appears to default the line-height to normal if it isn't specified. For example:

```
body{
    line-height:1; /* as seen in Eric Meyer's reset css */
}
p{
    font:normal normal normal 14px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

will result in all paragraphs having a normal line-height, overriding the 1 set for the body, while

```
p{
    font:normal normal normal 14px/1 "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

will retain the line-height of 1 (which in this example would be 14px).

Answer (score 9):

It seems that [`line-height` doesn't need a unit (detailled article)](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/).

> The property line-height can accept
>   unitless number values. You can also
>   give line-height united values, though
>   generally you shouldn’t. But unitless
>   numbers are just fine for this
>   property.

Comment: Thank you!  That really explains it--and lots of perplexing weirdness with my websites!  Yay!

Answer (score 7):

If no unit is supplied e.g. `"line-height: 1.5"` the distance between the lines is set as this number multiplied with the current font size.

1.5 x font-size

Answer (score 7):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp) and [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) line-height:1; is valid and means the following: Sets a number that will be multiplied with the current font-size to set the distance between the lines.

Answer (score 2):

It's a multiple of the font size. From the CSS 2.1 Candidate recommendation: »The used value of the property is this number multiplied by the element's font size.«

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In this image as you can see white area text headlines have a space above and below.
This is because of line-height default value is 110% to 120% in browsers that why this space is coming around to text. But If you Set:

```
line-height:1;
```

Then its default value will not affect the text and now there will no any extra height of text.
Results after using line-height:1; in code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Line-height: 1;` is close to the equivalent to the normal line height (it depends on the user agent).  According to MDN this is the preferred way of setting line height:

> [number] (unitless)
> The used value is this unitless  multiplied by the element's own font size. The computed value is the same as the specified . In most cases, this is the preferred way to set line-height and avoid unexpected results due to inheritance