# Why font-icons have extra height?

Tags: internet-explorer, custom-font

I'm using a set of icon Fonts that I created using [Ico moon](http://icomoon.io/app). The icons look and work great in Firefox and Chrome, but the icons appear in IE 10 with extra height.

I'm not sure where the height is coming from.

Here in IE 10, the icons are appearing to have a much greater height.
[image: IE icons with extra height]

Here is what they look like in chrome with the correct height.
[image]

Here is the CSS for the icons:

```
font-family: 'IconFont';
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

And here is the Traced Styles from IE10 Dev tools.[image]

I made a quick demo on codepen.io of a simliar problem.[Demo is here](http://codepen.io/ryanjgill/pen/Ihcbe)

Is anyone experiencing similar issues? Has anyone found a fix for this?

Comment: need to see the rest of your code. preferably in a fiddle.

Comment: have you tried to give the icons a `height`? If IE doenst find a `width` and or `height` its unsure about what to do.

Comment: @DiederikEEn That doesn't make sense. This is an icon **font**, as far as IE is concerned it's supposed to render an `inline-block` with 13px letters in it.

Comment: Oh dindt noticed it was a font, my fould

Comment: The font in the example on codepen doesn't load for me in IE 10 (using the default font). Besides that, are your icons that special so you need a custom font? The [Unicode subset of Dingbats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat#Unicode_Dingbats) might be enough if you're lucky. Or why not use small PNGs or SVGs?

Comment: You have `line-height: 1` without specifying any unit.

Comment: @Dai That is correct. No unit is needed. [What is line-height:1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000398/what-is-line-height1)

Comment: @Mario I do need to use this custom font. The icons I need are custom SVGs that I'm turning into the font.

Comment: @Mario Icon fonts are popular nowadays because they make it easy to preload all the icons your webapp needs in one HTTP request. They're also a bit cleaner for accessibility than CSS image replacement, particularly the ones that are based on ligatures like [Symbolset](http://symbolset.com/). PNGs aren't scalable, and SVGs are probably really really bloated when it comes to download size. **tl;dr**: the use of a font is mostly a performance hack that (ab)uses the fact that TTF is a really compact yet highly compatible black-and-white vector graphics format.

Comment: @Dai Also the traced styles say the line-height as-rendered is `18px`, that wouldn't account for the massive height increase.

Comment: The CodePen demo [looks fine in my IE10](http://i.imgur.com/o3GpZ9c.png?1).

Comment: @Jeroen If you open it with Chrome, it will have icons instead of those single letters next to each of the buttons labels.

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS reset script?

Comment: Any progress on this since I have a similar issue.
My 50ct go to the idea the svg is build up. Something todo with glyphs instead of matrix. When you save an *.svg from *.eps I believe this strips this line-height out. When you save to *.svg from *.ai You will need to manually 'unfatten' the layers, colors ... it's a wild guess since I have similar issue but no proper solution.

Comment: Your demo is not open in IE 10. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with line-height : 1

you write

```
line-height: 20px ;
```

Answer (score 0):

open your image in Microsoft office picture (or other Editor) and Resize your picture, IE browser sometimes shows pictures as them real size.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem like that and - I fixed it ))) In my svg files folder was a one wrong file. (With hidden element which had parameters X-1220 and Y-770) so it was a problem! I removed this element and everything was fine.