# How do I get text to align to top of div without any space

Tags: html, css

How do I get text to align to top of div without any space?

As you can see in this example there is a litle space between the top of div and the text: http://jsfiddle.net/8BSzp/

```
<div class="test">Text</div>

.test{color:#FFF; background-color:#066; height:200px;}
```

/Kind Regards

Comment: remove default browser padding and margin

Comment: margin-top: -4px; ? like this: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8BSzp/3/

Comment: I used Danields example. 

I have reset my CSS, changing margin/padding have no effect and changing line-height affects my design.

Danield post and answer?

Comment: @LasseBrosolatJensen - I posted my above comment as an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add `margin-top: -4px` to your class.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8BSzp/3/)**

If you were to change the line-height this would effect the line-height thought your text - which is not a desirable result... so using margin-top seems like a better option in your case.

Answer (score 4):

it is because you have not reset margin of body.

by default, every html tag has some styling properties associated. a better option is to reset all properties and then writing own styling code.

better explained [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and [here](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

```
body{margin:0;}
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BSzp/1/)

Comment: It will be better if you explain him what's causing that, anyways +1

Answer (score 2):

```
line-height: 1;
```

[read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000398/what-is-line-height1). [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVZKh/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to reduce the line height to get closer to the top inside the div. By default the div doesn't have any padding, so you need something else. Try:

```
line-height: 0.8em;
```

However, this will cause multiple lines of text to be closer together. I'm not sure if this will be a problem if your design. But this is probably the closest you get to the top of the div.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need the top of the characters to fit with the top of the div, you can set the line-height a bit smaller than the font-size.

```
line-height:12px;
font-size:14px;
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmvNa/)

I would advise against this though. If the text wraps on two lines, it will be unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Give this CSS

```
.test {
color: #FFF;
background-color: #066;
height: 200px;
line-height: 11px;

body{margin:0}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8BSzp/4/

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use reset the entire style to defaults so all browsers will have the same mark-up. This is due to the fact that many browsers have different default margins.

Here is the CSS that will reset the defaults.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

### Source: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/